# pyautogui.MoveTo no acepta los datos que le passo

Tags: python, socket

Hola estoy intentando crear un programa que pueda mover el mouse de otro ordenandor remotamente.
Estoy usando sockets para passar los datos entre los dos dispositivos.
Pero tengo un problema el pyautogui no me acepta los argumentos que le passo.

El error esta que en esta parte pyautogui.moveTo(daa)

daa deberia ser = 120,80

Y el codigo de error menciona que no encuentra ningun archivo con ese nombre.Quando obviamente no passo ni busco un archivo.

```
#codigo del servidor
while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept() 
    try:
        print('Conexión con {}.'.format(addr))
        while True:
            datos = conn.recv(4096)

            daa=datos.decode("utf-8")
            
            pyautogui.moveTo(daa)
            break
         
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

```
#Codigo del cliente
sock = socket.socket()

sock.connect((host, port))



pos = pyautogui.position()

px=pos[0]
  
py=pos[1]

px=str(px)

py=str(py)

soc=px+","+py

soc=str(soc)

print(soc)

sock.send(soc.encode("utf-8"))
```

```
#codigo de error que me sale.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cuent\OneDrive\Documentos\software\ser.py", line 28, in <module>
    pyautogui.moveTo(daa)
  File "C:\Users\cuent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 598, in wrapper
    returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cuent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 1280, in moveTo
    x, y = _normalizeXYArgs(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\cuent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 661, in _normalizeXYArgs
    location = locateOnScreen(firstArg)
  File "C:\Users\cuent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cuent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cuent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 373, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cuent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 353, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\cuent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 262, in _locateAll_python
    needleFileObj = open(needleImage, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1029,178'
```

Espero que alguien sepa la solucion,Gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo que tu le pasas es un string y la función espera 2 números, no sirve de nada que le pases '1029,178' deberías hacer slgo como `data = daa.split(',')` y luego pasas cada string a entero al momento de llamar a la función, algo así `pyautogui.moveTo(int(data[0]), int(data[1]))`

Comment: Gracias me ha ayudado